# Find distinct values of a column using JPA or entityManager with no SQLINjection scope

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to fetch distinct values of column, Column name is dynamic which user will provide.so dynamic query could be

```
public List<String> getDistinctValues(String paramName) {
    String query = "SELECT DISTINCT " + paramName+ "FROM tableName";
    return dataScalarDynamicQueryRepository.getDistinctValues(query);*/
}
```

It works well but it causes sql injection. To solve SQL Injection tried using JPA.

@Query(value ="SELECT DISTINCT (:paramName) FROM tableName", nativeQuery=true)
List getDistinctValues(@Param("paramName") String paramName)

assuming it is same as above query but result returns ["file_name"] instead of ["value1","value2"]

Could anyone suggest on this.

My DB is SQL Server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57761631/how-to-pass-column-name-dynamically-inside-a-query-annotation-using-spring-data ?

Comment: As a side note, if you must have a generic method like that, you can protect yourself from SQL injection by making the input param an enum, for example